# minimum connected subgraph containing a fixed set

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph, and let $S\subset V$. How to find a minimum subset $H\supset S$,and $G(H)$ is a connected graph.

It seems different from Steiner tree problem. Since in Steiner tree problem, the weight is added in edges and the goal is to find a tree.
While in our problem, the goal is to find a induced subgraph.

Comment: This seems like a generalised path-finding algorithm, which would be the special case $|S|=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is as hard as the Steiner tree problem for unweighted graphs. $G(H)$ might contain cycles, but a solution $H$ for your problem is a solution for the unweighted Steiner tree problem, since $G(H)$ is connected and therefore contains a spanning tree.

The Steiner Tree problem remains NP-complete even for unweighted graphs. See this question for details [Steiner tree problem for unweighted graphs](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19477/steiner-tree-problem-for-unweighted-graphs).